# Different response upon multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, jenkins, parameter-passing

I am unable to resolve an issue:

1. Using Jenkins / Groovy Script, I am executing a ps1 file with these argumets:

   ```bsh
   $myBuildTestNumber = "build-"+$env:BUILD_NUMBER;
   $rootDirectory = "\\\\myRootPath\\";
   $sn = "ibex.insight.reportrunner";
   Import-Module E:\\PSSDeployService.ps1 -ArgumentList $myBuildTestNumber,$rootDirectory,$sn
   ```
2. The .ps1 file goes like this:

   ```bsh
   Param(
       [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false)][string]$BuildNumber,
       [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)][string]$rootDirectorys,
       [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)][string]$serviceName
   )
   Import-Module E:\PSSDeployServiceModule.psm1
   # Here I am calling a function 'DeployServiceProc' from the .psm1 file with the parameters
   DeployServiceProc $rootDirectorys $BuildNumber $serviceName;
   ```
3. File .psm1 goes like this:

   ```bsh
   function DeployServiceProc($rootDirectory, $BuildNumber, $serviceName) {
       function backupServiceFiles($rd,$bn,$sn) {
           "In Function 'backupServiceFiles'..."
           "rd: ${rd}";
           "Build Number: " + $bn;
           "Service Name: " + $sn;
           $serviceStatus = Get-Service $sn;
           "Service Status: " + $serviceStatus;

           if ($serviceStatus -eq 'Stopped') {
               #"Service is stopped, taking backup";
           }
       }
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName "myRemoteSystem.Name" -ScriptBlock ${function:backupServiceFiles} -ArgumentList $rootDirectory,$BuildNumber,$serviceName -Credential $Cred
   }
   ```

The issue is:
If I don't provide three arguments, the code:

```
$serviceStatus = Get-Service $sn;
```

works just fine.

But if I provide all three arguments, the code returns:

> Service Status: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

I am unable to identify what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "don't provide 3 arguments"? Can you give an example for _both_ the call that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: Can you try to run your command by removing the quotation marks around the ${rd} variable and retry (probably that's the one of the 3 variables that when used you get this output?):

"rd: ${rd}";

"rd:" ${rd};

For some type of variables, using quotation marks outputs the variable type, not the actual contents of the variable.

Comment: Consider this:  

    function startService($sn)
     {
      "In Function 'startService'..."
      Start-Service $sn
      
      $maxRepeat = 20
      $status = "Running" # change to Stopped if you want to wait for services to start

     do 
      {
       $count = (Get-Service $sn | ? {$_.status -eq $status}).count
       $count;
       $maxRepeat--
       sleep -Milliseconds 1000
      }
      until ($count -eq 1 -or $maxRepeat -eq 0)
    
     }

Comment: the funny part is, I am copying a working function and modifying it just like the problem code, it works super fine.

function backupServiceFiles3($rd,$bn,$sn)
 {
  "In Function 'backupServiceFiles3'..."
  $rd;
  $bn;
  $sn;
  $status = "Stopped";
  Get-Service $sn
  $count = (Get-Service $sn | ? {$_.status -eq $status}).count;
  $count; #0 is Stopped, 1 is Running
  if($count -eq 1)
  {
   "in 1st block: Stopped";
  }
  elseif($count -eq 0)
  {
   "In 2nd block: Running";
  }
  
 }

Comment: Ok when you write  $serviceStatus = Get-Service $sn; you get the whole object but you want to display status if i am not mistaken? so try on the next line of code "Service Status: " + $serviceStatus.status;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to  run your command by removing the quotation marks around the ${rd} variable and retry (probably that's the one of the 3 variables that when used you get this output?):

```
"rd: ${rd}";

"rd:" ${rd};
```

For some type of variables, using quotation marks outputs the variable type, not the actual contents of the variable.

**Edit 1:**

Ok when you write

`$serviceStatus = Get-Service $sn;`

you get the whole object but you want to display status if i am not mistaken?

so try on the next line of code

```
"Service Status: " + $serviceStatus.status;
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Add this as a comment please. Thank you.

Comment: Nopes, i am still getting the same result for this modification.

Comment: Love you man. Its working.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You can check the link https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-basics-custom-objects. On Figure 2 it has a very good example on how .NET reference works in PowerShell.